# How to use aggregate function in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I'm getting below error while using aggregate function in where clause.

> 'An aggregate may not appear in the where clause unless it is a
>   subquery contained in a having clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer referrence'.

Query :

```
Select a.*,b.* 
from address a 
join account c on a.acct_no=b.acct_no 
where a.stop_date in (select max(a.stop_date) 
                      from address x 
                      where x.acct_no=a.acct_no and x.addr_code=a.addr_code)
```

Please suggest how to deal with it

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I tried to use x.stop_date, but it was resulting wrong data. Actually I'm converting oracle to sql. In oracle it worked fine.

Comment: "*I am converting Oracle to SQL*" does not make sense. Oracle ***is*** using SQL as its query language. You already use SQL

Comment: I'm not sure of DBMS, but I'm using sql server management studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

You should use `x.stop_date` instead of `a.stop_date`:

```
Select a.*,b.* 
from address a 
join account b on a.acct_no=b.acct_no 
where a.stop_date in (select max(x.stop_date) 
                      from address x 
                      where x.acct_no=a.acct_no and x.addr_code=a.addr_code)
```